# Allow user to mount USB

Tags: usb, permissions, mount, sudo, root

I have been using ubuntu 18.04 for over than 2 months now. I am using two different USB sticks (16GB and 32GB) and I insert them in laptop at least once a day, always with my user account (Vukasin). Since yesterday, I can't do it anymore. I get "not autorized to perform the operation". I understand that's a permission thing. When I run gnome-disks with sudo and then try to mount it, it works. But how is it possible that it just stopped working normally? What do I need to do to get my default settings and to be able to open any usb from files, as I was before (and as I am on my work PC that also runs Ubuntu 18.04).

Thank you for the answer everyone.

Comment: In a terminal window, `journalctl -f` while you plug in the sticks will give you some information. What type of filesystems? `lsblk -f` will show you.

Comment: Nothing interesting there, first command says I am not authorized to perform the action, second one that it's vfat or in my guess fat32. Any additional help? How can I authorize myself to mount it automatically every time?

Comment: I've had exact same for both SDCARDs and USB slots (about 5 devices) starting sometime after 13th Nov. Got a list of 73 updates which may have caused problem. Also got journelctl output, but it's too big for a comment. I've noticed a few similar threads recently. Note if I open a terminal and manually mount it (e.g. sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt) it works fine.